# Hide chart series Excel VBA 2013

Tags: vba, excel, charts, series

I would like to hide/unhide a series in a chart if it has a certain name. I am trying to use the following but it does not produce any result.

```
 For Each Series In refChart.SeriesCollection
        If Sheet2.Range("V42") = "No" Then
            If Series.Name = "Avg" Then
'both options don't work
                Series.Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
                'or
                'Series.IsFiltered = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

`refChart` is Chart type

Comment: what is your chart type? e.g. line, stacked column etc

Comment: @LubošSuk it's xlColumnClustered

Comment: You can hide a series like so in 2013 or later: `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).IsFiltered = True`

Comment: @Rory not working. It just doesn't do anything. No error no nothing.

Comment: More information please. If you took your car into a garage, would you just say "it's not working?" and leave them to it? ;)

Comment: I'm an automotive engineer, so I wouldn't take it to a garage :)  not sure what other info you are looking for. The `refChart` is a sheet with just the Chart (ChartSheet?). The actual `IsFiltered` and `Visible` fields go to `False` and `msoFalse` but in the graph it doesn't hide the series.

Comment: Found the (naive) mistake! I was using `Series.IsFiltered = False` instead of `= True` to hide the series.

Comment: Also see `Series.Format.Fill.Visible` along with `Series.Format.Line.Visible`.